# Убрать повторы и регистр первой буквы, цикл и регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, циклы

Написал такой код:

```
  var textt = "Представляет, дел, один-два, представляет, Один-два, Дел, Один-два";

    texttprep = textt.match(/[а-я-]+/giu);
    var lenres = texttprep.length;

    for(var i = 0; lenres>i; i++){

    textt = textt.replace(new RegExp('(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ_-])' + texttprep[i] + '([a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ_-]*)(?![a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ_-])', 'giu'),function(full_match, _1st_group){
    return(/-/.test(_1st_group) ? full_match + _1st_group : _1st_group + texttprep[i] + _1st_group)+"(слово)";
    });

    }
    textt
```

Получается ответ:

```
представляет(слово)(слово), Дел (слово) (слово), Один-два (слово) (слово) (слово), представляет (слово) (слово), Один-два (слово) (слово) (слово), Дел (слово) (слово), Один-два (слово) (слово) (слово)
```

Как делать так, чтобы первая буква была заглавной и пробелом как в исходном тексте, а `(слово)` добавилась только один раз (Нужно чтобы цикл подставлял только один раз).
Должен получиться такой ответ:

```
Представляет (слово), Дел (слово), Один-два (слово), представляет (слово), Один-два (слово), Дел (слово), Один-два (слово)
```

Comment: Может, достаточно будет `textt = textt.replace(/(?<![\p{Alphabetic}\p{N}])[\p{L}_]+(?:-[\p{L}_]+)*(?![\p{Alphabetic}\p{N}])/gu, (m) => m[0].toLocaleUpperCase() + m.substr(1) + " (слово)")`?

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew, Мне бы хотелось узнать почему в моем коде получается такой ответ: `представляет(слово)(слово)` Маленький регистр для первого слова, остальные слова нормально. Что не хватает или лишнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому что вы проходитесь циклом по строке и каждый раз заменяете все слова, в итоге делая замену по несколько раз над словом.

Что делает ваш код:

1. Имеем строку `Представляет, дел, один-два, представляет, Один-два, Дел, Один-два`
2. Разбиваем ее регуляркой `/[а-я-]+/giu` - получаем `"Представляет", "дел", "один-два", "представляет", "Один-два", "Дел", "Один-два"`
3. Проходимся циклом по словам из п.2 и заменяем его на то же слово, но прибавляя "(слово)"

Давайте продемонстрирую:

Заменяем: `Представляет`. Результат:
`Представляет(слово)`, дел, один-два,`Представляет (слово)`, Один-два, Дел, Один-два

Заменяем: `дел`. Результат:
Представляет(слово),`дел (слово)`, один-два, Представляет (слово), Один-два,`дел (слово)`, Один-два

Заменяем: `один-два`. Результат:
Представляет(слово), дел (слово),`один-два (слово)`, Представляет (слово),`один-два (слово)`, дел (слово),`один-два (слово)`

Заменяем: `представляет`. Результат:
`представляет(слово)`(слово), дел (слово), один-два (слово),`представляет (слово)` (слово), один-два (слово), дел (слово), один-два (слово)

Заменяем: `Один-два`. Результат:
представляет(слово)(слово), дел (слово),`Один-два (слово)` (слово), представляет (слово) (слово),`Один-два (слово)` (слово), дел (слово),`Один-два (слово)` (слово)

Заменяем: `Дел`. Результат:
представляет(слово)(слово),`Дел (слово)` (слово), Один-два (слово) (слово), представляет (слово) (слово), Один-два (слово) (слово),`Дел (слово)` (слово), Один-два (слово) (слово)

Заменяем: `Один-два`. Результат:
представляет(слово)(слово), Дел (слово) (слово),`Один-два (слово)` (слово) (слово), представляет (слово) (слово),`Один-два (слово)` (слово) (слово), Дел (слово) (слово),`Один-два (слово)` (слово) (слово)

---

Я не совсем понял суть задачи, поэтому не могу посоветовать решение, но источник проблемы нашел=)

Comment: вот это я понимаю объяснение=) Спасибо большое. А можно узнать почему самый первый `Представляет` притягивает к себе `(слово)`? Т.е. без пробела

Comment: @Ilnyr потому что вы заменяете не на `[Слово]` + `[пробел]` + `"(слово)"`, а на `[Символ перед словом]` + `[Слово]` + `[Символ перед словом]` + `"(слово)"`. Перед первым словом символа нету. Соответственно, он не прибавится перед "(слово)"